# Get back some colors in Finder's sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, themes

Since Lion, every item in the Finder's sidebar are gray. I miss the colors, as they were helpful to quickly find a specific item.
The problem is the same in Open File dialog box.

Do you know of a way to **get back some colors in the Finder's sidebar**?

I'm ok to modify files owned by the System (such as system images), but I'm not ok to use [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php). [This project](http://cooviewerzoom.web.fc2.com/colorfulsidebar.html) seems nice, but I don't want to use it.

Comment: What is the problem you have with SIMBL? At the moment using it with the ColorfulSidebar bundle is the easiest way to get the color back into the sidebar.

Comment: My main problem is stability. I have had some bad experience with it, and try to stay away from it.

Comment: ah, didn't know it had issues; I'll keep an eye out for you, since I'm in the same boat.

Comment: When you know the mechanism of injection it uses to modify apps, you prefer to stay away from it. Nice hack, but an hack anyway.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the mechanism you're referring to?

Comment: I have updated the answer to link to SIMBL homepage and a plugin using SIMBL to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't alone in wanting the color back.  Unfortunately, it looks as if the Finder code actually shifts the hue from the fully-colored icon resources that are included (see the Go menu in Finder, which has the colored versions).

According to a commenter on [this MacThemes Forum thread,](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16810907) the developer documentation actually details how to shift the hue in the same way that Finder does; with the associated speculation that we'll see grey icons in every app that has a sidebar in the future.

Looks to me as if you can bite the bullet and use ColorfulSidebar (with SIMBL) or live with the grey.